# Use AzureAppendBlobAppender to write text file in Azure blob

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

i am using AzureAppendBlobAppender from log4net.Appender.Azure to write to blob.
but the logs are getting generated in XML format. How can i get them in normal text file, just the way RollingFileAppender generates.

```
 <appender name="AzureAppender2" type="log4net.Appender.AzureAppendBlobAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
 <param name="ContainerName" value="#######" />
 <param name="DirectoryName" value="######" />
 <param name="ConnectionString" value="#####"/>      
  <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <bufferSize value="100" />
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">        
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger %machine - %message e:%exception%newline %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Since  log4net.Appender.Azure is open source and hence i could customize it.
i Found the solution by modifying the following method in AzureAppendBlobAppender.cs.

```
            private void ProcessEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
                {
                    CloudAppendBlob appendBlob = _cloudBlobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(Filename(_directoryName));            
                    var log = "";
                    if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.Error)
                    {
                    log = Environment.NewLine + string.Format("{0} Exception : " + Environment.NewLine + "{1}", loggingEvent.TimeStamp, loggingEvent.GetExceptionString());
                    }
                    else
                    log = Environment.NewLine + string.Format("{0} Information : " + Environment.NewLine + "{1}", loggingEvent.TimeStamp, loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(log)))
                    {
                    appendBlob.AppendBlock(ms);
                    }
                }
```